# R Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: # x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following the last set of code in https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/plot-some-variables-against-many-others, and have modified the code for my data.

In this code:

```
  t3 %>%
  gather(-Border, key = "var", value = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = Border)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()
```

I get this error message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k.

The code runs without the stat_smooth() command but I need the smooth line.

With the exception of one var with 20 values, every other var has between 5 and 6 unique values. How do I reduce k?
Is a k of 5 reasonable?
The sample size is 1,000.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Obviously, we don't have your data, but we can generate some data that reproduces your problem:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 150), y = rnorm(1500), 
                 group = c(rep("A", 1490), rep("B", 10)))[-1500,]

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = group)) + stat_smooth()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula = 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
#> Warning: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`
#> Caused by error in `smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec()`:
#> ! x has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k.
```

The reason for this error is that if any of your groups has over 1,000 data points, `stat_smooth` will by default use a generalized additive model on *all* your groups. From the docs:

> For `method = NULL` the smoothing method is chosen based on the size of the largest group (across all panels). `stats::loess()` is used for less than 1,000 observations; otherwise `mgcv::gam()` is used with `formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")`

This means that if one or more of the groups is very small, `stat_smooth` will end up running a `gam` regression with these default settings, which will fail due to the number of points being inadequate for the specified model.

We can fix this by specifying `method = "loess"` in `stat_smooth`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = group)) + stat_smooth(method = "loess")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Allan, thank you very much. The code is running now.